# Where is exchext.h?

Tags: windows-7, include, visual-studio-2003

I am using VisualStudio .NET 2003 on Windows 7. I get the error below while compiling one of my projects.

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'EXCHEXT.H': No such file or directory

The file EXCHEXT.h is supposed to be in *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\include* folder. I have searched everywhere but cannot find this file.

Can anyone give me a pointer to what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a while since the questions was posted, but kind of ran into this issue myself.  I checked the windows SDK and, sure enough, it wasn't there. Seems to have been dropped a while ago, even though it is highly needed, for this type of addin development.  I ended finding an old checked in copy I had, but also did come across this from google code: http://code.google.com/p/outcall/source/browse/trunk/exchange/include/EXCHEXT.H?r=8.

Hope this helps.